# rename a file after its subdirectory in DOS

Tags: string, batch-file, dos, file-rename

I need to rename a file after its subdirectory in a batch file on Windows 8. For example, I need to rename "C:\path\to\my\logs\machine0015\001.log" to "C:\path\to\my\machine0015\machine0015.log"

I need to completely overwrite the file name with the last-dir name. There is only one relevant file per directory.

I can't work it out. It's been a long time since I've done any .bat programming; I've managed to do the rest of what I need, but that last point has me stumped. I've tried messing around with FINDSTR or a FOR loop, but I can't seem to work out how to extract the name of the last subdir from a full path (with random dir names and path depth).

I'm allowed to write a temp file, but an exe or 3rd-party app would be highly throwned upon, probably not permitted. This needs to work on Windows Vista/7/8, not XP.

Thanks for any help,

Olivier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
for %%a in ("C:\path\to\my\logs\machine0015\001.log") do for %%b in ("%%~dpa.") do (
ren "%%~fa" "%%~nb%%~xa"
move "%%~dpa%%~nb%%~xa" "%%~dpb"
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much !

I tried to understand what you're doing, now my head hurts.

It works, except the last move statement... Is it supposed to move the file back up one level ?

Comment: I'm still getting errors, I've spent time making double-sure it's not coming from my stuff before (it was, partly), but I think your code is being thrown off by spaces and ] in the path and filename.
PS: I'm taking a break, been on it since early morning and it's... early morning, again :-p

Comment: Sorry, my bad, your stuff works standalone, I must be messing something up when I mesh it into mine... the French saying is "my eyes are no longer aligned with their sockets" (je n'ai plus les yeux en face des trous). I'll fix it tomorrow. Thanks an enormous lot, and kudos.